# which reason should the 10kers give to the 'closing' posts

Tags: discussion, support

If a post receives five closing different flags. how should the final closing tag for the post be ?

Thanks !

Comment: Deletion has no explicit reason. The implicit reason is always the same: the site is considered to be better without the post. _Closing_ on the other hand, needs five close votes (or a moderator) and the majority reason wins, in the case of a tie, the last cast vote (among the tied?), iirc.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about closing, which is distinct from deleting?

Comment: yes, okay. What about closing ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Deletion has no reasons. A post is either deleted or it isn't.</s>

That's because when a question is closed, we want to give the OP a chance to improve it (and himself) by providing a constructive explanation of why his question was closed.

We reserve deletion for posts without hope. They cannot be improved and add no value to the site. Therefore, they are completely hidden for anyone under 10k (and even from those, in the case of questions).

Basically, when you vote to delete, you are not prompted for a reason. You either vote or you don't.

***Please don't change your question drastically like that!***

The close reason that received most of the votes will be displayed. It's *extremely* unlikely (and I don't see a situation where it'll happen) when a question is a dupe, off-topic, not-constructive, not-a-real-question *and* too-localized, all at once.

Comment: I just edited my post. What about closing ? THanks

Comment: @Qiongjie: Please don't edit your question so drastically like that. If you have a different question, ask it as a different question.

Comment: @Qiongjie "Editing" is different than changing the question's content entirely.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question. You just said that the case is unlikely. However, it still has chance to appear. Then what will the the final one ?

Comment: Probably the close reason chosen by the last voter, @Qiongjie. That's what happens in the case of 1-2-2 ties.